# Fedora add reomote drive

Tags: fedora, sftp

I changed my operating system from Windows to Fedora a few days ago. So I am a really beginner in any Linux stuff.

My basic goal is to add a remote drive (my cloud drive) on start up so I can use it. I tried to create a bash script which will be executed on startup by using `sftp`. I found the following code

```
sshfs user@sftp.example.com:/targetpath ~/mountdir
```

My problem is that **this works with root permissions but it does not work with my user permissions**. Executing with my normal privileges I get the error `read: Connection reset by peer`. Because I want to execute this on start up I don't want to use root permissions.

Also I searched for a solution to save my user name and the password but I didn't find something yet so I don't have to type them in every time.

---

## Background

**Fstab**: I googled a lot which lead me to the `fstab` file at first. I spent a full day and ended up with breaking the system because the internet connection was not present when starting the system so the target disk could not be included (at least I think that's what was happening).

**Script (WebDAV, sftp)**: I then tried to use WebDAV with

```
mount -t davfs2 https://webdav.example.com ~/mountdir
```

but this also only works with root permissions (Error: `mount: only "root" can do that`). My next step was then to use sftp which kind of seems to work better. But then I got the error mentioned above (Error: `read: Connection reset by peer`).

I don't want to store the files locally because there is not enough disk space available.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid or very basic question but I don't find any way to go on. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should never run a script as root! I can come up with some reason to when to run a script as root, but in general, it is not a good idea. `sshfs` also does not need root to work! :)

This should allow you to mount a remote ssh filesystem with a password using `sshfs` (It would be better if you could use a certificate instead of a password).

`echo <mypassword> | sshfs <myuser>@<site.tld>:/ ~/<myfolder> -o workaround=rename -o password_stdin`

Replace `<mypassword>`, `<myuser>`, `<site.tld>` and `<myfolder>`.

Example:

`echo 4ghNZGpk182q8SvY0kw0 | sshfs diblo@ftp.diblo.dk:/ ~/diblo -o workaround=rename -o password_stdin`

**NOTE:** Make sure the mount folder `~/<myfolder>` exists or create it (Remember to create the folder from the Linux user you want to run the script):

`mkdir -p ~/<myfolder>`

Replace `<myfolder>`.

https://www.darklaunch.com/how-to-remote-mount-with-password-using-sshfs-and-stdin-ubuntu-sshfs-remote-mounting-mosso

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will defently check out certificates. But still it does not work. If I execute your script I still get the same error ``read: Connection reset by peer``. If I add ``sudo`` in front of your commands it works. Also I had some struggles with my password because it contains an "!". May that be the thing so normal users are not allowed to use "!"?